# DataTrigger with Value Binding

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

Why this doesn't work?

```
 <Style x:Key="ItemContStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Asset}" 
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                       Path=CurrentAsset}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used StyleSelector instead...

Answer (score 1):

Because `DataTrigger.Value` is not a dependency property.

Comment: So... how can I set background of ListView items according to some criteria?

Comment: I thought about Style, Setter, Converter and ConverterParameter but it doesn't work... 

ConverterParameter also can't get the binding - it's also not a dependency property...

Comment: I'm not sure you can, at least not easily... unless you create your trigger dynamically in code. Or perhaps you could inherit Setter and add a ValueBinding property... probably not so easy